# Check if "People Picker" field is empty [JavaScript]

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Just wondering if there is a way to check whether a People Picker field is empty using the function "PreSaveAction". I'm able to do it with other types of field (text field, dropdown field) but with People Picker field is not working with the same logic.

The example below is the way that I'm doing with text field.

```
function PreSaveAction() 
{

if(getField('field1').value == "" && getField('field2').value == "" && getField('field3').value == "" && getField('field4).value == "" && getField('field5').value == "" && getField('field6').value == "" && getField('field7').value == "" && getField('Produção - Emitente').value == "")
{
alert('Please, fill the fields bla bla bla bla..."');
    return false;

}else{
    return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The People Picker creates a div for it when it is rendered on the page.  Here is some code I use to see if the People Picker is empty and get the user account name if it is not:

```
function selectedUser() {
    var userAccount = "";
    var peoplePicker = $("div[title$='People Picker']");
    var peoplePickerValue = peoplePicker[0].innerHTML;

    if (peoplePickerValue != "") {
        peoplePicker = peoplePicker[0].firstChild.id;
        userAccount = peoplePicker.substr(4, peoplePicker.length);
    }
    return userAccount;
}
```

It is a little tricky, but you can get the values through jQuery.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreaciate your help! I found a solution right here: http://ravirapolu.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/assgin-current-user-into-people-picker.html

Answer (score 0):

Using [`SPUtility`](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/WikiFiles/docs/People%20fields.md) you can check if a people picker field has value by checking

`SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName(peoplePickerInternalFieldName).GetValue().length>=0`

The `length` property denotes how many users are selected in the people picker field.

You can use the same condition for multiple choice fields too.(Checkboxes).